# Syntax for PHP while($row =mysql_fetch_row...?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, joomla

I am trying to send SMS to multiple recipients. The code I am trying to achieve this is like this:
The problem I am facing is the message is being delivered to only the first record in the table.

Need some help, what & where I am going wrong?

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,mobile FROM members");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$mobile=$row[1];
$name=$row[0];

$request = "";
$param['mobileno'] = "91". $mobile;
$param['message']  = "Dear $name (organisation name) wishes you a very very Happy Birthday";
$param['username'] = "username";
$param['password']  = "password";
$param['sendername'] = "sender";
foreach ($param as $key => $val ){$request .= $key . "=" . urlencode($val);    
$request .= "&";}$request = substr( $request, 0, strlen( $request ) - 1 );
$url = "http://smsapi" . $request;
$ch = curl_init($url);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);exit;
curl_close( $ch );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stick to Joomla coding standards. Don't go using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and pose security threats.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();     
$query = $db->getQuery(true);    
$query->select('*')
->from('members');     
$db->setQuery($query);     
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

while($rows){
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
        $mobile = $row->mobile;
        $name = $row->name;
    }

    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how I will assign loadresult() to variable to $mobile or $name and again please confirm whether loadResult() here is appropriate as against loadObjectList()

Comment: Sorry it's not working. However if I am adding var_dump($rows);exit; after loadOjectList() I am getting the correct dump of arrays. So I think the code after that needs some changes.

Comment: I have tried applying the full code including the //rest of code. The SMS is going through. But the problem is the same as original i.e. SMS is being delivered to the first record in the table. So I think there is something in the SMS code as well, which is preventing the looping through the records.

Comment: ahh ok. It worked for me on a small test with the `foreach()` however I did not test it with the `while` loop